# How to modify shared memory (shmget/shmat) in C?

Tags: c, struct, shared-memory

I have a struct:

```
struct sdata {
    int x;
    int y;
    time_t time;
};
```

I create shared memory for the struct as follows:

```
size_t shmsize = sizeof(struct sdata);
shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, shmsize, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
```

Then I access the shared memory like this:

```
struct sdata *data = shmat(shared.shmid, (void *) 0, 0);
data->time = time(NULL); // function returns the current time
```

My question is pretty simple. Is this the right way to access/modify shared memory? Is this the best approach?

(I am using System V semaphores for synchronization and I haven't included that code. I just wanted to make sure I am accessing/modifying the shared memory correctly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, the only thing of note is that you are creating a PRIVATE shared memory segment, which means you'll have to transmit the shmid somehow to any other process that you want to have use it.

Comment: If the other process is `fork()`ed, then there's no problem with the IPC_PRIVATE as long as the shared memory is created before the `fork()`.  The caveat is valid in the more general case, though.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a way to create, then access or modify that shared memory.
However, you may have sychronizaton issues, and you could use e.g. Posix semaphores for that. See first [sem_overview(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview) man page.

Comment: thanks. i am fine with the synchronization. i was just worried about doing "data->time = time(null); or data->x = 5" and it messing something up.