# Segfault after accessing a structure in shared memory?

Tags: c, struct, posix, shared-memory

I have a problem with sharing values stored in a `struct` across processes. Below my code is simplified with only one process, which will increment the value `num2`. Whenever the process ends, `waitpid()` writes the `pid` of the process to *array*. Again this is simplified, in my bigger project  I have about 100 processes, which successively write their `pid`s in *array*. So every process sees the *array*. However, for every one of them the integer values in `struct` are different. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

typedef struct{
   int num;
   int num1;
   int num2;
   char *array;
} data;

void c_print(data *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   data *main_data;

   int pam_id=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(data), IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);
   if (pam_id == -1)
       fprintf(stderr,"error");
   int k=shmat(pam_id,NULL,0);
   if (k==NULL)
       fprintf(stderr,"shmat error");
   main_data=malloc(sizeof(data));
   main_data->num = strtol(argv[1],NULL,10);
   main_data->num1 = strtol(argv[2],NULL,10);
   main_data->num2 = strtol(argv[3],NULL,10);
```

Without `malloc` below, accessing `main_data` causes a *segfault*. However, other processes can not see variables stored in `struct` except for array.

```
  main_data->array = malloc(main_data->num2*sizeof(char));

  main_data->array[0]=fork();
  if (main_data->array[0]==0){
      main_data->num2+=2;
      exit(9);
  } else {
      waitpid(-1,main_data->array[0],0);
      c_print(main_data);
      return 0;
  }
  return 50;
}
```

Comment: Why are you prototyping `main()`?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967388/how-to-modify-shared-memory-shmget-shmat-in-c) is also very similar; the only difference being multiple pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `k` and not `malloc()`.  The address of `k` is shared among the processes.  I think you have misunderstood the **shm** api.  Ie, replace `main_data->array=...;` with `main_data->array=(void*)k;`  Each process will get a new copy of `main_data`.  You need to use `shmget` with the `num2*sizeof(char)`.

The memory you wish to be shared should use `shmget()` and `shmat()`.  `malloc()` will be allocated per process and will be initialized with a copy of the parents memory.  If the `num`, `num1`, `num2` are private or `const`, then your `data` structure can use `malloc()` and the array should use `shget` and `shmat`.  If you need both to be dynamically updated in all processes, then both must use `shget()` and `shmat()`.

Also, you should take care of data races.